# How to make the div contents fit into the parent div with height 100%?

Tags: html, css

I looked through many posts and still can't get this one to work...

My goal is **to style css only (no javascript) so that the height of DIV class "two" always fit into the DIV class "container".**

The container DIV's height could change like window resize that is why I would like my "two" DIV to be able to change the size accordingly. So I set the container DIV height to 300px here but it could be any px like 500px etc

Please let me know if you need more clarification. Thanks in advance!

http://jsfiddle.net/pn9Qa/

**HTML**

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='top'>some text</div>
    <div class='bottom'>
        <div class='one'>header</div>
        <div class='two'>items here</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container
{
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 3px solid red;
}
.top
{
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:pink;
    float:left;

}
.bottom
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: green;
    float: left;
}
.one
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: orange;
}
.two
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Explain in it simple words.

Comment: You say you want the class .two to fit into the class .container, but .two is the child of .bottom div. So how do you want the layout to look like?

Comment: @Stano: as long as the .two does not overlaps the border of .container

Answer (score 5):

[Here's one using `calc()`](http://jsfiddle.net/FVDdn/):

```css
width: -webkit-calc(100% - 60px); /* note, the space is necessary */
```

[Here's one using `display: flex`](http://jsfiddle.net/FVDdn/1/)

```css
display: -webkit-flex;
-webkit-flex-direction: column;
```

[Here's one using padding/margins and z-index](http://jsfiddle.net/FVDdn/3/):

```css
box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 60px;
position: relative;
top: -60px;
```

[Then, the old, do some math yourself version](http://jsfiddle.net/FVDdn/2/).

Brevity on prefixes used. Use http://caniuse.com/ if you need to see which ones are necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Add "overflow: hidden;" to the .container rule, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/pn9Qa/2/

```
.container
{
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 3px solid red;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need this: http://jsfiddle.net/pn9Qa/1/

```
html, body { height: 100%; }

.container
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border: 3px solid red;
}
.top
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:pink;
    float:left;

}
.bottom
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: green;
    float: left;
}
.one
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: orange;
}
.two
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: hmm.. if i'm not mistaken, your version of jsfiddle, the yellow part (class "two") is still overlapping the red border (container)